# how customers check their orders if they use guest checkout?

Tags: checkout

i'm going to enable the guest checkout, but how the customers can get their invoice without an account? How shop owner identify the buyer when he came to the shop pickup the goods?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Customers who used the Guest Checkout could check their orders online by using the **Orders and Returns** link which should be at the bottom op your stores page. It will lead them to the following page:

`yourdomain.com/sales/guest/form/`

Here they can lookup their order by the order ID. If the order is paid, there will also be a link to the invoice available for the customer to print. Please note that invoices are only created upon completing the payment. So this link won't be available if the order isn't paid yet.

To identify the buyers when they come and pickup their goods at your store you could ask them to either:

- bring a printed version of the order confirmation email (for unpaid orders), or
- bring a printed version of the invoice (for paid orders)

To setup automated emails for orders and invoices go to:

`System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails > Order (and) Invoice`